# How do I remove the licensing error notice on Acrobat 9 Pro?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm getting the following notice in Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro:

> :Error "Licensing for this product has stopped working ..."

How do I remove this?

Comment: Needs More explanation.

Comment: Haha yeah, I have a "licensing error" with a lot of Adobe software.

Answer (score 3):

Register it - (Never seen a problem on people who have a genuine licence key, but anyway...)

Assuming you have a legal copy

Close all Adobe programs, then Keep the directory, but delete all files in -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe PCD
```

Next, restart any Adobe program in the same suite or just Adobe Acrobat if you purchased it on it's own (If part a suite, you have to activate other programs first).

Now register, it should activate fine. If you have a problem activating now, Contact Adobe directly. You pay so much for the products, they offer support!

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is often "FLEXnet" which verifies the authenticity of your Adobe Program. Removing it results in the licensing error.